# Max cell value from a stacked raster

Tags: raster, r

How can I find a max cell value from a stacked raster.

```
Rmax <- maxValue(RAD1998.all[[1]])
```

works fine but

```
Rmax <- maxValue(RAD1998.all[[2]])
```

gives NA.

Of course not in a stacked raster.

Here is my code:

```
RAD1998 <- raster(paste(getwd(), "/1998bil/1998ASC5min_ppt_spas1214_0001_19980202_0810_UTC.asc.bil", sep = ""))
list.ras <- mixedsort(list.files(paste(getwd(), "/1998bil/", sep = ""), full.names = T, pattern = ".asc.bil")) 
RAD1998.all <- stack(list.ras)
```

Comment: Are you looking for the maximum of all the layers or the maximum of each layer? Anyway, you are not using `maxValue` the correct way. According to the help page, you better use additional argument `... Additional argument: layer number (for RasterStack or RasterBrick objects)`

Comment: I am looking for the maximum of all the layers to have a same scale like my.at <- seq(0, max cell value of all layers, increment). Thanks, Nahm

Comment: I got it with cellStats                                    #http://geostat-course.org/system/files/lewis_tutorAM.pdf
Rad1998.max <- cellStats(RAD1998.all, 'max') 
Rad1998.all.max <- max(Rad1998.max)
Rad1998.all.max

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following example shows two ways to get at the max raster value in a stack.  The first utilizes `max()` which also gives you a host of other useful information.  The second method uses `maxValue()`, which gives just the max value of both the rasters in the stack

```
library(raster)  

# Generate some georeferenced raster data
x = matrix(rnorm(400),20,20)
rast = raster(x)
extent(rast) = c(36,37,-3,-2)
projection(rast) = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

y = matrix(rnorm(400),20,20)
rast2 = raster(y)
extent(rast2) = c(36,37,-3,-2)
projection(rast2) = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

raster = stack(rast, rast2)

# Now run the statistics
max(raster) # Provides min, max and additional details  # Example 1

maxValue(raster)  # Gives both values                   # Example 2...
maxValue(raster)[[1]] # Gives first in stack max value
maxValue(raster)[[2]] # Gives second in stack max value
```

---

```
> maxValue(raster)  # Gives both values
[1] 2.688376 2.971443
> maxValue(raster)[[1]] # Gives first in stack max value
[1] 2.688376
> maxValue(raster)[[2]] # Gives second in stack max value
[1] 2.971443
> 
> max(raster) # Provides min, max and additional details
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 20, 20, 400  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.05, 0.05  (x, y)
extent      : 36, 37, -3, -2  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : -1.457908, 2.971443  (min, max)
```

Answer (score 0):

`max(MaxValue(raster))` will provide the maximum value of all rasters in the stack.